# Merge Cells Vertically in RTF

Tags: rtf

I need to programmatically generate an RTF document with a table that has a column vertically merged., e.x.

```
______________________________
|  merged | foo    |  hello   |
|  cell   |        |          |
|  right  |--------|----------|
|  here   | bar    |  world   |
|_________|________|__________|
```

I looked up online and found that the codes are \clvmgf and \clvmrg
but I can't find a decent example.

I made a text rtf using MS word, but there's too much junk rtf codes in it for me to figure it out where to put the \clvmgf and \clvmrg to get this to work.

Could someone give me an rtf for above example table with no extraneous rtf codes so I can figure out how \clvmgf and \clvmrg works?

Any additional explanation would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the table in word, copy it then paste it into WRITE.EXE & save.
I doubt it uses the minimum amount of codes but it's better than the stuff word spits into it.

Comment: Just tried in Windows 7, because I had a similar idea. Windows 7 WordPad seems not to support merged cells correctly, though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already and Wordpad just unmerged the cells.

Comment: Works for me (xp) FWIW here is the RTF with the same layout as your example http://pastebin.com/2cAF3KvD

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your example at the pastebin site!

Answer (score 3):

Here's simple RTF for the table you presented:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
\fs20\viewkind4\uc1

\trowd \clvmgf \cellx2972 \cellx6053 \cellx9134\pard\intbl merged cell right here\cell foo\cell hello\cell\row
\trowd \clvmrg \cellx2972 \cellx6053 \cellx9134\pard\intbl\cell bar\cell world\cell\row
\pard\par
}
```

I took the example from Alex-K and simplified it to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

please check this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bzhtmlcss2rtf/

http://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/working-rtf-html-css-and-script-files-with-my-own-packages-java-and-php/

This example is help to you.